# Расширение связывающей таблицы Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется 3 сущности: студент и преподаватель, унаследованные от простого класса `User`, и предмет. Мне необходимо будет получать информацию об оценках студента по предметам определённых преподавателей.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor : User
{
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }     // Куда мне добавить это поле??
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}
```

Здесь у меня создаются таблицы `User`, `Subject`, `StudentSubject` и `InstructorSubject`. И, собственно, я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы поле `Score` попало в таблицу `StudentSubject`. Можно дописать вручную в миграцию, но хотелось бы всё же, чтоб автоматически добавлялось...

Comment: [говорят](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053747/entitiy-framework-update-database-from-model-instead-of-generate-database-fr) есть расширение для дизайнера

Comment: @teran, ну говорят, в Москве кур доят) мне-то интересен именно CodeFirst. Не может быть, чтоб нельзя было решить эту задачу, но сам решения не могу придумать..

Comment: а я вам что-то про DB-first написал разве?

Comment: @teran вы написали про Model First

Comment: или же SqlQueryстолбец этот добавить потом...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автогенерированная таблица-связка, реализующая отношение many to many, расширена быть не может.

Создайте отдельную сущность StudentSubject со связями к Student и к Subject, и туда уже добавляйте Score.

А еще лучше - делайте сразу сущность Score, со связями к Student, Subject и Instructor. Так вы избежите странного ограничения "1 оценка на предмет" и сможете хранить кто из преподавателей поставил эту оценку.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, краткое описание, как в CodeFirst можно связать 3 таблицы связями "многие-ко-многим"? Никак не могу обозначить ключи...

Comment: @guitarhero Откуда у вас появилась третья таблица и связи "многие ко многим"?

Comment: простите, оценку только один препод может поставить... Но как я могу расставить ключи?

Comment: @guitarhero а в чем, собственно, проблема? И повторяю: откуда у вас взялись связи "многие ко многим"?

Comment: Ну вот смотрите: одну оценку каждый препод может поставить нескольким студентам. Значит, таблица "оценивание" связана "многие-ко-многим" со "студентами", "многие-ко-многим" с "преподавателями" и "многие-ко-многим" с "предметом", если я правильно понимаю...

Comment: @guitarhero подумайте еще раз

Comment: @guitarhero почему во фразе *"одну оценку каждый препод может поставить нескольким студентам"* у вас фигурируют три разные сущности? Связи-то двусторонние, а не трехсторонние!

Comment: Так-с, пораскинув мозгами, я пришёл к выводу, что таблица должна содержать ID студента, ID предмета, ID преподавателя, получаемый по ID предмета, ну и, собственно, сама оценка, никуда не привязанная. Ведь так?

Comment: @guitarhero да, именно так. Еще можно добавить туда суррогатный ключ. А можно не добавлять, сделав первичным ключом комбинацию из нескольких внешних (если эта комбинация по условиям предметной области уникальна).

Comment: А теперь мы подошли к изначально поставленной проблеме :D Я совершенно не представляю, как в данном случае обозначить свойства ключами... В моём представлении, внешние ключи расставить при помощи OnModelCreating и, в случае успеха, каким-то образом сделать комбинацию...

Comment: @guitarhero это в вы о чем? Может, отдельный вопрос зададите?